# How to summarize a long text using Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, jsp, web, jstl, thymeleaf

I have an object with two attributes, one is the id and the other is an attribute of the type strring called TEXT (postgres database) that is used to store the text of a post from a client.

When the application loads these posts on the page, for it does not be a text  too long,I would like to summarize this text.

I was able to do this using JSP, in an easy way, using `forTokens`.

How to do the same as the below code using thymeleaf?

```
<p class="post-text">
    <c:forTokens var="summary" items="${p.text}" delims=" " begin="0" end="60">
            ${summary}
    </c:forTokens><a href="<c:url value="/${p.link}" />">[Keep reading...]</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thymeleaf has the abbreviate function

see the documentation in this url: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html

> /*  * Abbreviate text making it have a maximum size of n. If text is
>   bigger, it  * will be clipped and finished in "..."  * Also works with
>   arrays, lists or sets  */ ${#strings.abbreviate(str,10)}
>
>   // also array*, list* and set*

thus, you can have something like that

${#strings.abbreviate(summary,60)}

Comment: Glad that I helped!